# How does ownership skew impact queues?

Tags: queue, ownership, largedatavolumes, data-skew

I have queues that are assigned more than 10k records, and their records are included in reports and list views.

Most of the documentation about ownership skew is around a User owning records. How does ownership skew relate to / impact queues?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership_data_skew.htm